# Error in convert factor to numeric with R

Tags: r

Update:

## acturally, my problem is `sum(data[,"employee_count"], na.rm = T)`

I have original data as:

```
employee_count
1-49
0
150-249
1-49
1000+
```

I wrote code as following:

```
data$employee_count<- as.character.factor (data$employee_count)
data[data$employee_count=="1-49","employee_count"]<-1
data[data$employee_count=="50-149","employee_count"]<-2
data[data$employee_count=="150-249","employee_count"]<-3
data[data$employee_count=="250-499","employee_count"]<-4
data[data$employee_count=="500-749","employee_count"]<-5
data[data$employee_count=="750-999","employee_count"]<-6
data[data$employee_count=="1000+","employee_count"]<-7
```

Then the data is changed as following:

```
employee_count
"1"
"0"
"3"
"1"
"7"
```

Then I try to change it to numeric:

```
data$employee_count<-as.numeric(as.character(data$employee_count))
```

Data is changed to `1 0 3 1 7` after the code, but when I tried to do  `sum(data$employee_count)`, and the output is `NA`. I suppose there is something wrong.

The desired result is to actually changed this column to numbers, which can be involved in any kind of calculation.

For example, if I wrote `data[1,"employee_count"]+data[2,"employee_count"]`,

the desired result will be 1+0 = `1`.

If I wrote `sum(data$employee_count)`,

the result should be 1+0+3+1+7=`12`.

If I wrote `data[3,"employee_count"]*data[4,"employee_count"]`

the result should be 3*1=`3`.

Comment: What is the desired result?  Please add it to your question.

Comment: `as.character.factor` is new for me.

Comment: Me too.  Apparently it's just `levels(x)[x]`, which is actually less typing.

Comment: @RichardScriven  desired result for `sum(data$employee_count)` should be 6. (1+2+3)=6, not na.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum(as.numeric(factor(data[,1], levels=unique(data[,1]))))
#[1] 6
```

If you check the `order`

```
 as.numeric(factor(data[,1], levels=unique(data[,1])))
 #[1] 1 2 3
```

which is not the same as

```
 as.numeric(factor(data[,1]))
 #[1] 1 3 2
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(employee_count = c("1-49", "50-149", "150-249"
 )), .Names = "employee_count", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

#### Update

```
 data <- structure(list(employee_count = c("1-49", "0", "150-249", "250-499", 
 "1-49", "500-749", "500-749", "750-999", "50-149", "1000+", "150-249"
 )), .Names = "employee_count", row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")


 data1 <- data

 data[,1] <- as.numeric(factor(data[,1], 
          levels=c('0', '1-49', '50-149', '150-249', '250-499', '500-749', '750-999', '1000+')))-1


 data[,1]
 #[1] 1 0 3 4 1 5 5 6 2 7 3

 data1[,1]
 #[1] "1-49"    "0"       "150-249" "250-499" "1-49"    "500-749" "500-749"
 #[8] "750-999" "50-149"  "1000+"   "150-249"

  sum(data[,1])
  #[1] 37
 data[3,"employee_count"]*data[4,"employee_count"]
 #[1] 12  #different value because I used a different data
```

Comment: Order wouldn't matter if all you want is the `sum`

Comment: @Richard Scriven  Yes, it wouldn't matter, but I was referring to the assignment OP was trying to do

Comment: I am not sure what levels are... but it changed my data. > `data[1:20,"employee_count"]
 [1] "1" "0" "1" "3" "1" "1" "7" "1" "0" "1" "1" "1" "1" "5" "1" "2" "1" "7" "5" "0"`it changed to `> data[1:20,"employee_count"]
 [1] 1 2 1 3 1 1 4 1 2 1 1 1 1 5 1 6 1 4 5 2`

Comment: @wrwerwerwe  It is not clear how your dataset structure will be.  Please `dput` the example dataset just like I updated with the data .  I thought you had only 3 levels in your dataset.  Seems like there are many ranges.

Comment: @wrwerwerwe  When you update, please also show the expected result so that there will not be much confusion

Comment: @wrwerwerwe  `dput` would have been better.  Anyway, I will try to construct one other dataset as all the levels were not shown in your example data

Comment: @wrwerwerwe  I updated with a new dataset.  Please check